# Unable to set background image using python (2.7.3), bash and gnome3

Tags: bash, python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
bashCommand = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/malon/autowallpaperchanger/" + pic_name
print bashCommand
os.system(bashCommand)
```

Print result:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/malon/autowallpaperchanger/wallpaper-1252048.jpg
```

Copying and pasting the print result into a terminal makes the change successfully, so the command is correct, but `os.system` isn't processing the request correctly for some reason. In the full script (posted below), I use `os.system` for a different reason immediately before (wget) and that works fine.

Full script [here](http://pastebin.com/R90GTmBZ).

Comment: Do you need to use os.system instead of subprocess.popen2 ?

Comment: @aking1012 If I knew, I wouldn't be asking :P  Also, I already am using os.system

Comment: You didn't understand what I asked.  Do you have some reason for using os.system instead?  or is popen okay?

Comment: @aking1012 Oh, I understand your phrasing now. I'm not very familiar with popen, but i don't think there would be a reason why I couldn't. Upon reading about popen/subprocess, it seems overly complicated. I don't need to pass any variables or use any return values. Just to execute one static line of code. is subprocess the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: the same question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12198538/4279)

Answer (score 5):

Drop all the `os.system` and `subprocess` stuff. Just use the Gio/gsettings API, like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gio

settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.background")
settings.set_string("picture-uri", "file:///path/to/image.png")
```

Comment: nice.  i wasn't thinking about other ways to do it.  i just went with os.whatever has been deprecated for a while in favor of subprocess.  i get a brain-lock thing when i see things implemented one way and just try to get that way working.

Comment: @Timo This is excellent, advice I haven't seen before. Here is my updated (but still not working) script:

http://pastebin.com/19QtFLZq

Comment: Do a check that your file actually exists: `print "Does my new image exists?", os.path.exists("/home/tyler/autowallpaperchanger/" + pic_name)`

Comment: @Timo

This is what prints:  
  
  
Does my new image exists? True.

Also, I'm not sure how to format these responses nicely... but here again is my most updated version of the script (including your image checker): http://pastebin.com/8EDDBEJ9

Comment: The script works perfectly fine here, my background gets changed to a random image. I just changed your image path with `os.getcwd()` for convenience.

Comment: @Timo Can you try this version of the script ( http://pastebin.com/fpUAjT69 )? I basically did what you said you did and used os.getcwd() for convenience and it still doesn't work for me. I run dual monitors, could that be why? I use a single image for both screens, default ubuntu 12.04 settings (x86). I also use the latest beta nvidia drivers, but `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` returns the correct background, so I don't think any of thatshould matter. Any ideas?

Comment: @malon make sure to convert the path to a valid uri. `settings.set_string("picture-uri", "file://" + urllib2.quote("/home/tyler/autowallpaperchanger/" + pic_name))` spaces must be encoded to `%20` etc.

Comment: `settings.apply()` might help if it is a delayed setting otherwise it is a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
import shlex, subprocess, os, sys

def change_wp(fname, folder_stem='Pictures'):
    home = os.environ['HOME']
    uri = os.path.join(home, folder_stem)
    uri = os.path.join(uri, fname)
    set_wp_command = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://" + uri
    args = shlex.split(set_wp_command)
    try:
        my_proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
        my_proc.wait()
    except:
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    change_wp('mywallpaper.png')
    print("Wallpaper changed...")
```

It anticipates mywallpaper.png existing in ~/Pictures.

Comment: `bashCommand = "wget " + page_source[address_start:address_end]  
os.system(bashCommand)`
bashCommand = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/tyler/autowallpaperchanger/" + pic_name 
print bashCommand
args = shlex.split(bashCommand)
my_proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
my_proc.wait()

I attempted to modify your code to no avail. I presume that is because there is some magic happening in os.path.join and os.environ ?

Comment: I gave you the working chunk for changing the wallpaper.  All you have to do is hand it the right directory as folder_stem and the right file name as fname.